# Swift Xcode 8.3 localizable.strings not working?

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring, xcode8

I've created new project with `localizable.strings` , but the translation is not working

**the file root** `"localizable.strings"` :

```
 - Project
 -- localizable.strings
```

**file content :**

```
"TEXT_PRINT" = "Testing is worked";
```

and the localization is active on both languages English and Italian, unfortunately 
when i try to print it out with localizedString the out put always `"TEXT_PRINT"` when its should be `"Testing is worked"`

**Swift code :**

```
let testText = NSLocalizedString("TEXT_PRINT", comment: "")
alert().normalAlert(title: "", body: testText, vc: self)
```

any idea why its not working ?

Comment: It should be `"Localizable.strings"` – with an upper-case "L"

Comment: Double check whether Localizable.strings is added to target?

Comment: Yeah already renamed it to `"Localizable.strings"` still same issue

Comment: How you are changing language in app or you have selected italian as default language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the solution maybe this will help someone else , i am using Instagram login library and its already content `Localizable.strings`

how did i found it out ?

go to your project then -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources , and check there where is this file located

good luck